# UdpClient.EnableBroadcast value has no effect

Tags: c#, .net, udp, udpclient

I was just playing around with a `UdpClient` and noticed setting `UdpClient.EnableBroadcast` to `true` or `false` doesn't have any (side)effect, I am able to broadcast with it either way:

```
using (UdpClient client = new UdpClient())
{
    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello");
    while (true)
    {
        client.Send(data, data.Length, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 45678));
        Console.WriteLine("sent");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

[The MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.enablebroadcast.aspx) is rather vague on this, but it sounds like it should cause an exception if you broadcast with the property set to `false`:

> Gets or sets a Boolean value that specifies whether the UdpClient may
>   send or receive broadcast packets.
>   ...
>   true if the UdpClient allows broadcast packets; otherwise, false. The default is false.

Not a critical issue, but it just made me wonder. Is this a bug or is the property just there so you can refer to it later and find out whether you are meant to broadcast with it or not?

Comment: I've noticed the same behavior and wondered the same thing.  It's not clear what this property is designed for, but indeed we can apparently send broadcast packets regardless of the setting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the broadcast mode when you initialize the udp socket, something like as under

```
this.someUdpSocket.EnableBroadcast = true;
this.someUdpSocket.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));
```

New Edit:

Above doesn't work and the below code

```
this.someUdpSocket.Client.EnableBroadcast = false;
```

also does not serve the purpose. So as for your answer "Yes it can be called as a bug or the property might be relevant in some other context."

But if you want to disable the broadcasting explicitly you can do it like as under:

```
this.someUdpSocket.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Udp, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, false);
```

Thanks for the motivation.

Comment: This is irrelevant. The point is that I _am able to_ broadcast, while the "broadcast mode" is _"disabled"_.

Comment: Check "New Edit" apologize for making it short before and not relevant to question asked.